# MySQL use of GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table of people, each one has the *number of visits* and the *priority*:

```
ID | NAME          |  VISITS | PRIORITY
---------------------------------------
 1 |     John      |    1    |   0
 2 |     Joe       |    2    |   1
 3 |     Peter     |    1    |   1
 4 |     Sara      |    0    |   2  
 5 |     Phillip   |    5    |   0
 6 |     Bob       |    3    |   1
 7 |     Andrew    |    4    |   2
```

There are only certain allowed priorities: (0,1,2)

**How do I create a query which gives me people ordered by the number of visits (starting from the lowest) but within their corresponding priority groups?**

So the result should look like this:

```
ID | NAME          |  VISITS | PRIORITY
---------------------------------------
 1 |     John      |    1    |   0
 2 |     Philip    |    5    |   0
 3 |     Peter     |    1    |   1
 4 |     Joe       |    2    |   1  
 5 |     Bob       |    3    |   1
 6 |     Sara      |    0    |   2
 7 |     Andrew    |    4    |   2
```

I suppose there has to be some use of the GROUP BY clause, but Im not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use ORDER BY and two columns.

```
SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY priority, visits;
```

Comment: @JackDouglas Actually you're right... technically the ORDER BY clause is "ORDER BY priority, visits" and the right term would probably be "Subject".

Answer (score 8):

Did you just try `ORDER BY`:

```
select id, name, visits, priority
from people
order by priority, visits
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d3cc/1)

Comment: Sure, but this orders the table only according to the priority column.

Comment: @NumberFour no, it doesn't. it orders by both priority and visits.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select * from table order by priority, visits
```

note: the ID column wont have the order on your result cause every visit already has it's id, your result should look like this:

```
ID | NAME          |  VISITS | PRIORITY
---------------------------------------
 1 |     John      |    1    |   0
 5 |     Philip    |    5    |   0
 3 |     Peter     |    1    |   1
 2 |     Joe       |    2    |   1  
 6 |     Bob       |    3    |   1
 4 |     Sara      |    0    |   2
 7 |     Andrew    |    4    |   2
```